# What is the difference between rs-api and jsr311-api

Tags: jax-rs, jsr311

Both seem to provide the same interfaces but I could not find a definite answer on what the difference between the two is (and which one to take).

- JSR311: https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/index.html
- rs-api: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/ws/rs/package-summary.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jsr311 site is the original spec site for JAX-RS 1.1.  The docs.oracle.com site is the API docs site for Java EE 6.

Using either should be fine, JAX-RS 1.1 was included in Java EE 6.